# Groovy 2.5.6 compatibility with jdk 1.7

Tags: java, groovy, maven-surefire-plugin

Unable to run compile Groovy(2.5.6)/Spock class on jdk1.7

I apologize in advance if this has already been answered or if it is a trivial question.

I am using Groovy 2.5.6 which according to the Groovy web site supports JDKs from 1.6 to 1.8. During my maven build with JDK 1.7, both Java and Groovy classes are compiled and the jar is built properly.

The problem starts to come when the maven-surefire-plugin comes into the picture. It tries to execute the Spock test and that's when I get hit with the nasty error **`Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/domain/billing/asf/biz/adjustmentmodify/AdjustmentModifyActivitySpec : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 ->`**

I have spent almost all day trying to figure this out with no luck. If anybody knows of a fix, please share. I am stuck with Java 1.7 unfortunately. I was relying on the fact that Groovy is supposed to be compatible with this JDK.

Comment: You may need to configure the `targetBytecode` parameter if you're using GMavenPlus.

Comment: The class com/domain/billing/asf/biz/adjustmentmodify/AdjustmentModifyActivitySpec is compiled with JDK8 and therefor can not be loaded by 7.  Without the setup you are running its hard to guess, why that is the case).  Most likely you built with 8 and now run the test with 7 too?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy 2.x is not compatible with JDK17. Groovy 3.0.x started to be compatible with JDK16. You have to use Groovy 3.0.8 (http://groovy-lang.org/changelogs/changelog-3.0.8.html ) and migrate Spock to 2.0

Update: I read JDK17 not JDK7 :facepalm:

Comment: That's ok, I was looking for if Groovy 2.5.6 did support JDK17, so this answer at least helped me.